# Bi-direction multithreaded socket connection

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, bidirectional

The situation is as following:
There is a server and a client, which both can initiate a command/message to each other.

Because the server can send a message at any time, the listening on the socket is done in a separate thread (a `ListenerThread`). This is all fine. The client can send messages and receive at the same time, however, how would you know if a certain response belongs to the command you sent when the server can also initiate a new command/message to notify that something happened?

If I send a message to the server, and the server responds with "OK" in the listening thread. How would you know this is the actual response of the message/command you sent (keeping in mind this is another thread). What if the server received an update from another client and sends that update first.

This like a chat application, though with an actual response for every sent command.

example case:

> Let us say that the protocol only consists of a `move <playernum> [<x>,<y>]` command which indicates that a player has done a move (server notifies client) or that a player wants to do a move (client notifies server). Also, the server responds with "OK" if the move was okay or with "ERR" if not.

**Safe state:**

```
     move 1 [3,4]
client ---> server

        OK
client <--- server
```

**Unsafe state:**

```
    move 1 [3,4]
client ---> server

    move 2 [1,2]
client <--- server

        OK
client <--- server
```

The client did not expect this response... should responded with OK.

Comment: Pass a message ID with each command and pass it back with the response.

Comment: The server only replies to the client that sent the command. The server knows which `Socket` is sending data, it shouldn't send "OK" to all the clients just because one client sent data. This isn't an issue. This is like asking "how do I know who I'm talking to when I'm in a group of people".

Comment: @teppic That would kinda work, however I am not responsible for the server part ;(

Comment: Your protocol (thus server) is broken.  Work arounds will ‘happen to work’ until they don’t.  The real fix is replace the protocol.

Comment: Do you know if the server sends a newline with a command response (or a move from another player)?  In other words, is it safe to block on readLine()?

Comment: @Ian Mc yes the server sends a newline, however there are messages which are two lines long (from the server, another difficulty).

Comment: @mevets Yeah I know, would have done it differently too, but I'm not in the position do to that right now.

Comment: The answer did not help?  Perhaps I misunderstood your issue.  Let me know if there is anything further you need.

Comment: @IanMc Your answer explains very well how to handle the bi-directional threading part (listening and processing at the same time). However, the following problem is linking the response with request. Because multiple requests can receive the 'OK' response. I would like to know for which command 'OK' response is when you send 2 commands very rapidly. Hopefully, that is more clear? If you have the answer, you're my hero, and I will accept your answer

Comment: I see.  So the _same_ client can send two moves rapidly?  If this is true, how does the client remember which are the two commands?  Are the commands stored in a List, or something similar?  Or is that two _different_ clients send two moves rapidly, and _each_ client receives both `OK` messages?  If it is the first, I can help.

Comment: The first, it's not that the client sends moves very rapidly. Its more that the network can be slow and 1st response could arrive as the second which was not intended. However, now I'm thinking. Is that even possible with TCP? I thought about passing the command to the networking layer (in java), storing it. And when there is a response just link it to that response somehow, but then you could have the same problem right?

Answer (score 2):

You have a protocol where the client can read one of three possible messages:

1. `OK` (The move you made was accepted)
2. `ERR` (The move you made was rejected)
3. `move PLAYERID <co-ord1,co-ord2>`

It is a reasonable assumption that the messages `OK` and `ERR` will only be sent back to the socket which requested a `move`.  However a legal `move` is broadcast to all other players (perhaps excluding the player who moved).

Since you can receive unsolicited responses (the moves that other players make), you have correctly created a listener thread.  You have not described the action your application takes when it receives a `move` message from another client, but I will assume that your listener thread handles that case.  What remains is how to co-ordinate your `move` commands, and the response to that which will appear in the listener thread.

To synchronize the submission of your `move` command, and the response, a BlockingQueue (called `queue`) will be used , and shared between the client and listener.  The form of this will be:

Client:

```
out.println(command);   // Where out is the socket PrintWriter stream
String response = queue.take();   // Where queue is the BlockingQueue
// Process either `OK` or `ERR`
```

Listener Thread:

```
while ((command = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("OK") || command.equalsIgnoreCase("ERR"))
        queue.put(command);
    else if (command.startsWith("move")) {
        // Process a move
    }
    else 
        System.out.println("Unrecognized command="+command);
}
```

As you can see, the client simply submits a command, and blocks for the response of "OK" or "ERR".  The requirement for processing other player moves has moved into the listener thread.

The listener processes all three conditions (Another player move, an "OK" or an "ERR").  The messages responses "OK" and "ERR" are sent back to the client.  A move command is processed separately, and as such is not the responsibility of the client making the moves.

Below I have mocked working code which demonstrates these concepts.  The server will randomly (with equal probability) respond with:

1. OK
2. ERR
3. A multiline response which includes `OK` and another player's move

Code:

```
public class MoveGame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String command = "";

    new Thread(new MoveServer()).start();

    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out = null;
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<String>(10);
    try {
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 5001);
        out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        new Thread(new ClientReader(socket, queue)).start();

        while (!command.equals("quit")) {

            command = scanner.nextLine();
            if (command.startsWith("move")) {
                out.println(command);
                String response = queue.take();
                System.out.println("Client got response="+response);
            }
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        scanner.close();
        out.close();
        try {
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

static class ClientReader implements Runnable {

    private final Socket socket;
    private final BlockingQueue<String> queue;
    public ClientReader(Socket socket, BlockingQueue<String> queue) {
        super();
        this.socket = socket;
        this.queue = queue;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        BufferedReader in = null;
        try {
            in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String command;
            while ((command = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("OK") || command.equalsIgnoreCase("ERR"))
                    queue.put(command);
                else if (command.startsWith("move")) {
                    System.out.println("A player made a move: command="+command);
                }
                else 
                    System.out.println("Unrecognized command="+command);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

static class MoveServer implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        Random random = new Random();
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(5001);
            while (true) {

                System.out.println("Listening for new connections");
                socket = ss.accept();
                System.out.println("New session has started");
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

                String command;
                while ((command = in.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Got command="+command);
                    int responseType = random.nextInt(3);
                    if (responseType == 0) 
                        out.println("OK");
                    else if (responseType == 1)
                        out.println("ERR");
                    else {
                        out.println("move 1 [3,4]");
                        out.println("OK");
                    }
                }
                in.close();
                out.close();
                socket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}

}
```